# Javascript - Recursion - Iterate json with ability for user to skip

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, recursion

I am implementing a trending feature on my site and was wondering the best approach for handling user click events within a recursive function.

Code example:

```
var trendingCodes = [];

// trendingCodes is json populated by ajax, this part works fine and not included for brevity
//   looks like {code:'SadPanda', text:'Thanks for checking out my !shouttag', img:false}

// Kick this pig
showTrendingCode(0, 200);

function showTrendingCode(indexCurrent, fadeSpeed)
{
    var indexNext       = ((indexCurrent + 1) % trendingCodes.length);
    var trendingCode    = trendingCodes[indexCurrent];

    if (trendingCodes.length > 1) {

        // !!!! Problem
        //  I am trying to register an event handler for the 'next' trending code
        //    but if I click multiple times it causes a 'maximum stack exceeded' error
        jQuery('#trending-refresh').off().on('click', function()
        {
            showTrendingCode(indexNext, 200);
        });

        jQuery('#trending-text p').add(jQuery('#trending-title span')).add(jQuery('#trending-refresh')).fadeIn(fadeSpeed);

        setTimeout(function () { showTrendingCode(indexNext, 600); }, 5000);
    }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to register an event handler for a dom element (next), but if the user clicks on the link several times I get the 'maximum stack exceeded' error. If the user doesn't click at all then the function runs fine (in perpetuity, which is desired effect).

Any suggestions to make this work as desired?

Here is le fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o1ekr6g3/

Comment: When you click, you are calling `showTrendingCode` twice, once from the click and once from your `setTimeout`, which I believe is the root of the problem.  You should probably return before the `setTimeout` if a click occurs.

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippet or jsfiddle to demonstrate ? Would try substituting `.one()` for `.on()`

Comment: Updated with fiddle. @RickT: makes sense. (at)guest: I'll give that shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using recursion, I opted to separate the iterator function from the presentation function, so the final result looks like:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#trending-text p').text('Loading...');
        $('#trending-title span').text('Loading...');
    },
    datatype: 'json',
    url: '<?php echo url_for('@ajaxTrending') ?>',
    success: function(data) {

        if (data.status == 'success') {

            jQuery.each(data.content, function(code, message)
            {
                if (message.length >= <?php echo $messageLength ?>) {
                    message = message.slice(0, <?php echo $messageLength ?>) + '...';
                }

                trendingCodes.push({code:code, img:false, text:message});
            });
        }

        else {

            trendingCodes.push({code:false, img:false, text:false});
        }

        // This makes the initial call to the iterator function
        setTimeout(function() { showTrendingCodes(); }, 500);
    }
});

// Iterator function
function showTrendingCodes()
{ 
    var counter = 1;

    // Show first code via separate function
    showTrendingCode(trendingCodes[0], 300);

    if (trendingCodes.length > 1) {
        setInterval(function()
        {
            showTrendingCode(trendingCodes[counter++], 300);

            if (counter >= trendingCodes.length) {

                counter = 0;
            }
        }, 3500);
    }
};

function showTrendingCode(trendingCode, fadeSpeed)
{
    var $moneyshot  = jQuery('#trending-moneyshot');
    var $refresh    = jQuery('#trending-refresh');
    var $title      = jQuery('#trending-title span');
    var $text       = jQuery('#trending-text p');

    $text.add($title).fadeOut(fadeSpeed, function()
    {
        if (trendingCode.code) {

            $moneyshot.attr('href', '/!/' + trendingCode.code);
            $text.text(trendingCode.text);
            $title.html('<a href="/!/' + trendingCode.code + '">!' + trendingCode.code + '</a>');

            $text.add($title).fadeIn(fadeSpeed);

        } else {

            $title.text('!SADPANDA');
            $text.text('Nothing is trending right now...');

            $text.add($title).fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
        }
    });
}
```

---

This solution works fine, and does not result in the error mentioned in OP.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a variable to reference timeout if defined, using `.stop()` , `clearTimeout()` , substituting `.one()` for `.on()`

```
var timeout = null;

showTrendingCode(0, 400);

function showTrendingCode(indexCurrent, fadeSpeed) {
if (timeout) {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  $("*").stop()
}
  var indexNext = ((indexCurrent + 1) % trendingCodes.length);
  var trendingCode = trendingCodes[indexCurrent];

  jQuery('#trending-text p').add(jQuery('#trending-title span')).fadeOut(fadeSpeed, function() {
    if (trendingCode.code) {

      jQuery('#trending-title span').html('<a href="/!/' + trendingCode.code + '">!' + trendingCode.code + '</a>');
      jQuery('#trending-text p').text(trendingCode.text);

      jQuery('#trending-moneyshot').attr('href', '/!/' + trendingCode.code);

      if (trendingCodes.length > 1) {

        jQuery('#trending-refresh').off("click").one('click', function() {
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          $("*").stop(true, true);
          showTrendingCode(indexNext, 200);

          return true;
        });

        jQuery('#trending-text p').add(jQuery('#trending-title span')).add(jQuery('#trending-refresh')).fadeIn(fadeSpeed);

        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
          showTrendingCode(indexNext, 600);
        }, 1000);
      } else {

        jQuery('#trending-text p').add(jQuery('#trending-title span')).fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
      }

    } else {

      jQuery('#trending-title span').text('!SADPANDA');
      jQuery('#trending-text p').text('Nothing is trending right now...');

      jQuery('#trending-text p').add(jQuery('#trending-title span')).fadeIn('slow');
    }
  });
}
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o1ekr6g3/1/

---

Edit, Updated

Try defining `indexNext` outside of `showTrendingCode` ; substituting `.delay()` for `setTimeout()` ; using `.promise()` , `.then()`, `.fail()` ; declaring `click` event and handler for `#trending-refresh` outside of `showTrendingCode`

```js
var trendingCodes = [{
  code: 'FOOBAR',
  text: 'This is my !shouttag',
  img: false
}, {
  code: 'SADPANDA',
  text: 'This is another !shouttag',
  img: false
}];

var elems = jQuery("#trending-text p, #trending-title span, #trending-refresh");

jQuery("#trending-refresh").click(function() {
  elems.stop().promise().fail(function() {
    showTrendingCode(indexNext, 400)
  })
})

var indexNext;

showTrendingCode(0, 400);

function showTrendingCode(indexCurrent, fadeSpeed) {
  indexNext = ((indexCurrent + 1) % trendingCodes.length);
  var trendingCode = trendingCodes[indexCurrent];
  if (trendingCode.code) {

    jQuery('#trending-title span').html('<a href="/!/' + trendingCode.code + '">!' + trendingCode.code + '</a>');
    jQuery('#trending-text p').text(trendingCode.text);
    jQuery('#trending-moneyshot').attr('href', '/!/' + trendingCode.code);

    if (trendingCodes.length > 1) {
      elems.fadeIn(fadeSpeed).delay(3000)
        .promise()
        .then(function() {
          $(this).fadeOut(fadeSpeed).promise().then(function() {
            showTrendingCode(indexNext, fadeSpeed)
          })
        })

    } else {

      jQuery('#trending-title span').text('!SADPANDA');
      jQuery('#trending-text p').text('Nothing is trending right now...');

      jQuery('#trending-text p, #trending-title span').fadeIn('slow');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#trending-text p,
#trending-title span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="trending-wrap" class="clearfix">
  <a id="trending-moneyshot" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <img class="pull-left" src="/image/local/global/trending_image_default.png" />
  </a>
  <div id="trending-text-wrap">
    <div id="trending-title" class="spacerBottomMedium">
      Trending: <span class="bold"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="trending-text">
      <p></p>
      <a id="trending-refresh" href="javascript:void(0);" style="display:none;">
        <img class="pull-left" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o1ekr6g3/6/

Comment: I saw these changes in your fiddle, can you explain what the $("*").stop() call is doing? I was thinking of passing `clicked` (per @RickT comment) in as a 3rd arg, and checking to see if true, if true then just return without making the 2nd call.

Comment: `$("*").stop()` was included to stop current ongoing animations called by `.fadeIn()`

Comment: Makes sense. Your solution appears to fix the maximum stack exceeded issue, but if I do several clicks, then stop and let it go back to normal, it repeats the most recent one several times.

Comment: _"but if I do several clicks, then stop and let it go back to normal, it repeats the most recent one several times."_ Not certain interpret "repeats the most recent one" correctly? Repeats displaying `!FOOBAR` consecutively ?

Comment: Correct. It will repeat several times, then go back to normal rotation.

Comment: Could not reproduce. Tried clicking lower image three times within 1-5 seconds; same `a` element is not displayed consecutively , here

Comment: I'll double check my code, I may have missed something.

Comment: Hmmm I updated with my code and I can recreate the repeat/lag issue: https://jsfiddle.net/o1ekr6g3/3/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103886/discussion-between-mike-purcell-and-guest271314).